# Revoke Personnel User Consent Azure V2

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've a web app which access Microsoft Graph API which authenticate the user using Azure v2.0. Both Personnel User account and Organisational user can provide the user consent and access the app. Organisational user can remove the consent by going to myapp.microsoft.com however Personnel user are not able to see the consented app in myapps.microsoft.com

So how can personnel user remove the consent to the application ?

Thanks,
Himal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users with personal Microsoft accounts (Hotmail, live, outlook.com, etc.) can revoke apps at https://account.microsoft.com/privacy/.  If you click on `Apps and services that can access your data`, you'll see a list of all the apps you've consented to and you can revoke them there as well.

[image: Apps and services]

For example, I test the Graph explorer app with a live.com account.  I can review the permissions it uses and revoke the application if necessary.

[image: graph explorer revoke consent]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly i was looking for.